# Simplifying an infinite sum which might involve a power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, power-series, fractions

I have the following expression:

$$ \frac{\frac{\bar{N}^N}{(N-n)!}(1-q)^{N-n}}{\bar{N}^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\bar{N}^k}{k!}(1-q)^k}$$

where $n,N,\bar{N}$ are positive integers, $n\leq N$, and $0\leq q\leq 1$.

I'm trying to simplify this, but I'm having a hard time getting anywhere. It took a lot of manipulation to get to this point, and I was hoping that I would be able to make use of some power series, since the sum looks a lot like the power series for an exponential function, except for the lack of relationship between $\bar{N}$ and $q$.

Does anyone have any advice? If there's something obvious that I'm missing, I'd prefer a hint, since this *is* a homework problem.

Comment: The sum indeed is the exponential function, as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\bar{N}^k}{k!} (1-q)^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\bar{N}(1-q))^k}{k!}=e^{\bar{N}(1-q)}$.

Comment: @blablablup thanks for clearing that up for me. I knew I was close but I just couldn't get it to solidify. If you post this as a comment I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were right, the sum is indeed the exponential function:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\bar{N}^k}{k!}(1-q)^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\bar{N}(1-q))^k}{k!} = e^{\bar{N}(1-q)}. $$